# How to set up links in Activeweb?

Tags: activeweb

An initial application url is

```
http://localhost:8080/activeweb-bootstrap-custom/
```

A freemarker's template link looks like

> href="/test"

The problem is when I click the link then the application url changes to
http://localhost:8080/test. 
Obviously the application name is lost.
How can I set up application to open links with full url? The link should be

```
http://localhost:8080/activeweb-bootstrap-custom/test
```

Comment: can you  provide a full text of your link? Are you using <a> anchor or some other means?

Comment: @ipolevoy <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="/test" role="button">test controller</a></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have has nothing to do with ActiveWeb or Freemarker. Any JSP or plain HTML works the same.

When your first character is "/", the browser makes a new URL that points to a root context. Just remove the forward slash to point to current location:

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="test" role="button">test controller</a></p>
```

tx